# Funcion Recursiva que busque un valor negativo

Tags: python, recursión, spyder

Necesito implementar una función recursiva que, dada una lista, devuelva la posición del primer valor negativo (considerando que el primer elemento de la lista tiene posición 0), o `−1` en caso de que no exista ninguno.

Por ejemplo, dada la lista `[2,4,-6,-8]` la función debe devolver 2; dada la lista `[2,4,6,8]` debe devolver -1.  He intentado hacer el ejercicio de varias formas pero no logro encontrar la solución.

Mi código :

```
def buscar_negativo (numero):

    if numero != 1 :
        return -1 

    else:
        return buscar_negativo(numero) +1



lista = [0,4,3,5]

print (buscar_negativo(lista))
```

Comment: Mi principal problema es que no se como hacer para que recorra una lista en busca de un valor especifico en este caso un valor negativo haciendo que me devuelva los valores explicados en el ejercicio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La idea realmente es muy simple:

- La función debe aceptar dos parámetros, uno la lista y otro el índice que esa llamada debe comprobar.
- Cuando la función sea llamada se pueden dar tres situaciones:

  1. El índice es igual a la longitud de la lista, esto implica que no es un índice válido, o la lista está vacía o se ha iterado por completo sin encontrar un negativo, en este caso retornamos -1.
  2. Si indizamos sobre la lista usando el índice y el valor es negativo retornamos el índice.
  3. Si no es negativo llamamos a la función recursivamente, pero incrementamos el índice en uno. Debemos retornar la salida de la función para establecer la cadena de llamadas recursivas, que terminará cuando alguno de los anteriores returns tengan lugar.

---

```
def buscar_negativo(lista, indice=0):
    if len(lista) == indice:
        return -1
    elif lista[indice] < 0:
        return indice
    return buscar_negativo(lista, indice + 1)
```

> ```
> >>> buscar_negativo([1, 2, 3])
> -1
>
> >>> buscar_negativo([-1, -2, -3])
> 0
>
> >>> buscar_negativo([])
> -1
>
> >>> buscar_negativo([4, 5, 7, -3])
> 3
> ```